# How to make a webpage load to a particular resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have designed a (non-responsive) website in my machine which has a native resolution of 1920x1020. But, most of the machines nowadays come with 1366x768 resolution in which my website looks jagged up. I want it to load in a particular fixed resolution. How can I do that?

Comment: Make it responsive. Why have you designed a site for a monitor resolution that isn't a standard one?

Comment: Convert it in to bootstrap.

Comment: "most of the machines nowadays come with 1366x768 resolution" - this is not true. Nowadays, people could be viewing your website on a wide range of devices/resolutions, and you need to develop with this in mind. You should look into making it responsive using CSS3 Media Queries

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.

Browsers provide no API to reconfigure a user's graphics drivers.

Even if it was possible, it would be a terrible idea since modern screens tend to give poor rendering when not run at their native resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Designing a site that only looks good in 1920x1020 is not a good idea. There are two basic options:

1. Wrap all your content in a `<div>` which has a fixed width. Then use that width as the basis for your design. Use `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` to get the content in the middle. This is the way Stack Overflow is designed. On a bigger screen there will be empty space on the sides. On a smaller screen there will be a scroll bar.
2. Create a responsive design that properly scales down. Harder but better.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are browser addons that can help you on this. They resize your broswer to sizes that you want to test. for chrome you can use this extension 
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resolution-test/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal 
   You can find firefox addons with similar functionality.
2. If you want a rough check on how responsive your site is then for checking on a higher resolution zoom out in your browser. for lower resolutions you can zoom in. but the disadvantage here is you can only visualize in resolutions that are of same aspect ratio of yours so you need to resize the browser to that particular aspect ratio and then do the zooming.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

at the beginning that's all you need to do

```
 body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }

 #mainContentDivInsideBody{
    margin:auto;
    width: 990px; //or more
    height: 100%;
 }
```